# Reset the AutoIncrement sequence number in Xamarin/sqlite-net-pcl Nuget pkg

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

When I clear my table, I would also like to have the autoincrement rowid number reset.  I found several posts that recommended this code:

```
DeleteAll<mytable>();
Execute("update sqlite_sequence set seq = 0 where name = 'mytable';");
```

When I run it, I don't get any sort of error, but the rowid is not reset. I have also tried:

```
Execute("delete from sqlite_sequence where name = 'mytable';");
```

... with the same result. Is there a quirk with sqlite-net-pcl that makes this not work? Or am I missing something?

The table definition looks like this:

```
public partial class mytable : IHasId
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    <other stuff deleted>
}
```

and IHasId is:

```
public interface IHasId
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

(Don't shoot me, I wrote this back when I can has cheeseburger was a thing. It amused me at the time... And, no, the table isn't actually named mytable.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found it! I'm happy to report it was something stupid-ish. In our other (very old, C++-based) database application, our tables are plurals, and the indexes are singular. For example, the "Customers" table contains records with an index column named "customer". So in that spirit, for my "Customer" objects, I had the database open a file named "Custs.db3".

Because the examples used "table" I was doing this:

```
Execute("delete from sqlite_sequence where name = 'Custs';");
```

What I needed was:

```
Execute("delete from sqlite_sequence where name = 'Customer';");
```

So... The indexes are not stored by "table" name, they are stored by "object" 
class name.